# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in visual studio log file

Tags: windows, visual-studio, plugins

I use visual studio 2019. When I open my solution, sometime I can see this alert:

[image]

If I click by Open log btn, I can see a log with the following exception:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Элемент не найден. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================
```

So, actually, it was not a problem for me, before this time. Now I need to install [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=frhagn.Typewriter). And it seems to me, this error prevent for correct installation.

I go to Extensions -> Marketplace -> type "typewriter" - plugin name. Then I press Download. After this I try to restart Visual Studio. Finally, I see the following message:

[image]

"Элемент не найден" - means: element not found.

I press on the View install log and again, I see exception about COM:

```
08.10.2020 16:38:48 - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Элемент не найден. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration2.GetInstanceForPath(String path)
   в VSIXInstaller.LocationBasedSKU..ctor(String appidInstallPath, String appidName, Version vsVersion, String edition, String rootSuffix)
   в VSIXInstaller.LocationBasedSKU..ctor(String appidInstallPath, String appidName, Version vsVersion, String edition, String rootSuffix, IntPtr alternateUserToken)
   в VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   в VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   в VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack, IDictionary`2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Full visual studio reinstall solved my problem! And don't remove installation cache [according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263898/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-in-visual-studio-log-file)